# Modifying property value from other component not updating the view angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to modify/update some property of component from other component.

The property is getting set to new parameter but it is not updating the view.

**pagetitle.ts**

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<h2 [innerHTML]="title"></h2>'
})
export class TitleComponent {
  private title: string = "Initial Title";
  setTitle(param) {
    this.title = param;
  }
}
```

**appcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TitleComponent} from './seo.title';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: `<h3>Some text</h3>`,
  providers: [TitleComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private updateText: TitleComponent) {
    updateText.setTitle("his text is passed to child");
  }
}
```

*setTitle function is receiving the parameter perfectly and updating the property(this.title) too, but the view is not getting update.*

I do not want nested component handling. I want to update the property so that i can utilize anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **some** `TitleComponent` instance but that surely is not the instance shown on your page. You can't just inject `TitleComponent` to your constructor and expect that this will be the right instance.

In this case it probably won't even be a component but only an instance of the components class.

For more details about how to communicate between components see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

`TitleComponent` injected into your `AppComponent` is not the same instance as the one displayed
If you want to be able to update the title form anywhere in the app, you need to use a service registered in the `AppModule`
Note that `title` property in `TitleComponent` is observable, and I used `async` pipe - that way displayed title will update whenever underlying observable emits a new value.

That way, any component/service that imports `TitleService` will be able to update the title.

Look at the following snippets (imports ommited for the sake of simplicity):

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TitleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    TitleService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**pagetitle.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<h2 [innerHTML]="title | async"></h2>'
})
export class TitleComponent implements OnInit {
  title$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private titleService: TitleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title$ = this.titleService.title$;
  }
}
```

**title.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  private titleSource$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Default title");

  get title$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.titleSource$.asObservable();
  }

  setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.titleSource$.next(newTitle);
  }
}
```

**More read:**
[Angular2 component interactions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)
[Rxjs documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Property Decorator

```
export class ExampleComponent {
@Input()
exampleProperty: string;
}
```

https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators#decorator-functions

Comment: It will be better if you add some explanation about your code.